# Change localhost url

Tags: hostname

I want to change localhost url
http://localhost:8081/bsamaraci/index.php/welcome/account_data 
to
http://mydomain.cc/bsamaraci/index.php/welcome/account_data
it's even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For that you have to let know your computer which machine resolve that name so for local purposes just add an entry like this in your hosts file (/etc/hosts in Linux):

```
127.0.0.1    mydomain.cc
```